# Modify javascript files with an event

Tags: javascript, events, onchange, gpx

i work with the freeware tool gpxviewer (https://www.j-berkemeier.de/GPXViewer/) to visualize gps tracks.

***my question:***
I would like to implement a dropdown to the html to change the appearence and scaling.
There are javascript files where i would like to change some parameters while the site is open.
Is it possible to make a  menu, which opens the js files, modifies some line of codes and reload the page with the new parameters?

```
<select id="dropdown" onchange="changeFunc();">
    <option value="variante1" selected>Variante1</option>
    <option value="variante2">Variante2</option>
    <option value="variante3">Variante3</option>
</select>
```

lines in javascript file i would like to modify with the select-menu (example):

```
JB.Scaling = {
   bandwidthDownmin: 0,bandwidthDownmax: 150,
   hardscaling:true
};
```

thank you for your help

Comment: *lines in javascript file* what javascript file? Is this code you've written or part of the "tool"? You don't want to re-write the Js files you need to store your parameters somewhere then use them dynamically

Comment: That said to do that you'll need some kind of "redraw" method to call which may or may not be in the code. TBH (don't take this the wrong way)but I feel you're out of your depth here

Comment: the code is part of the "tool". for example there is a defs.js with standard parameters for scaling, color etc. this parameters i would like to change with the dropdown menu

Answer (score 0):

Scripts running in web browsers cannot edit files on the server like this directly. If they could, literally anybody could make literally any change they wanted to your site. No offense, but this should be 100% obvious to you before you work on a project like this. If it isn't, you really need to do some [reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn) first.

As for how to actually do something *like* this... You can simply assign over values in JB.scaling as I'm doing here:

```
JB.scaling.bandwidthDownmin = 10;
JB.scaling.bandwidthDownmax = 200;
```

However, as comments have mentioned, this probably won't do anything because your "tool" almost certainly won't check these values and make updates unless you explicitly tell it to. For that, it will need to have a function you can call. See if you can find it in the documentation. I'd help, but I can't read German. :\

Note that telling the "tool" to redraw is distinct from actually reloading the page. Reloading the page is what happens when you click the "refresh"  button on your browser. This effectively throws out the page you're looking at-- along with any local changes you've made to its contents-- and requests a fresh copy from the server.

You can trigger this with Javascript, but if you do it, you'll be throwing away any changes you've made to these values, as well as which option the user has selected from the drop-down. In order for their choice to persist between page loads, you'll have to use [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) or [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). You could also set up a database to store things on the server, but that's probably overkill.